# How to avoid Enter functionality in VF page?

Tags: visualforce-component

I have created one vf page for creating the opportunity from the Custom object. There one button called create opportunity will be available. If the user fill the form and Click the create opportunity button or press Enter key then the opportunities will be automatically created from this page. But my client don't want the Enter functionality when creating opportunities he needs the opportunity creation functionality only by the way of clicking Create button. I think Enter functionality is the inbuilt functionality in Salesfore. Please help me in avoiding this. Also see my client comment for the reference.

**When using the NHS Site Convert, if you press  at any stage it will then immediately create the opportunities even if you are just pressing  as part of filling the Account and Salesperson fields.  Focus needs to be removed from “Create Opportunity” button so that pressing  doesn’t immediately lead to the opportunities being created.**

Thank you,
Regards,
Arun.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235716/disable-keyboard-enter-key

you can use the solution of above link.Javascript function can be written to prevent this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried the below java script code in all the input fields and Command Button to avoid Enter functionality while creating the opportunity in my own visual force page.It is working very well for me.

**onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){this.blur();actionFunction();}"**